# Using Get-ADGroup to bulk owner (ManagedBy) from several AD Groups through PowerShell

Tags: powershell

[Delftstack](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/powershell/get-adgroupmember-multiple-groups/#:%7E:text=Get%20ADGroupMember%20From%20Multiple%20Groups%20in%20PowerShell%20Use,-Identity%20%24group%20-Recursive%29%20%7D%20%24results%20%7C%20Format-Table%20-AutoSize)

```
$groupNames = "Group1", "Group2", "Group3"
$results = @()
foreach ($group in $groupNames) {
  $results += (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive)
}
$results | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

How to modify it to gather Owner of several AD Groups information?

`Get-ADGroup -filter { Name -like "*Group1*" } -Properties managedBy | Select ManagedBy`

Comment: `Get-ADGroup -Identity $group` should work (just like with `Get-ADGroupMember`)